# A convergent sequence of non-expansions converges uniformly on a totally bounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Here's a theorem that I tried to prove:

Let $V,d_V$ and $W,d_W$ be metric spaces and $(f_n)_n$ a sequence of non-expansions that converges to a function $f:A \subseteq V \rightarrow W$:
$$ f_n:\ A \subseteq V \rightarrow W$$
If $A$ is totally bounded, then the convergence is uniform.

Proof:

Fix an $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$.

1. Because $A$ is totally bounded, there exists a set of open balls $B_V(x_i,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$ that encompasses $A$:
   $$ A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_V(x_i,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$$
2. Because $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$, we find:
   $$ \forall i\in\{1,\dotsc,k\}, \exists n_i \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}:\ n\ge n_{i}\Rightarrow d_{W}(f_{n}(x_{i}),f(x_{i})) < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$
3. Because every $f_n$ is a non-expansion, we find:
   $$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\ d_{W}(f_{n}(x),f_{n}(x_{i})) \le d_{V}(x,x_{i}) < \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$
4. Because a convergent row of non-expansions converges to a non-expansion, we find:
   $$ d_{W}(f(x),f(x_{i})) \le d_{V}(x,x_{i}) < \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$

Now let $n^* = \max_i\{n_i\}$ and fix $x\in V$.
There exists a $x_i$ within an range of $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ around $x$.
For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, greater than $n^*$, we now find:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
|f_n(x) -f(x)|
&\le |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(x_{i})| + |f_{n}(x_{i}) - f(x_{i})| + |f(x_{i}) - f(x)|\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} +\frac{\epsilon}{3}\\
&= \epsilon
\end{array}
$$
This concludes the proof.

Is this proof correct?
I would appreciate comments on style and strategy as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof seems correct to me. I would suggest another proof, which seems to be more abstract, but actually is equivalent to yours.

First of all it is useless the hypothesis that $A \subset V$. Simply replace $A=V$, and say that $A$ is a totally bounded metric space. Call $\overline{A}$ the completion of $A$. Then $\overline{A}$ is totally bounded and complete, hence compact.

Second: all functions $f_n$ and $f$ are Lipschitz continuous. In particular, they can be extended to $\overline{A}$ uniquely.

Finally: since $\overline{A}$ is compact and all involved functions are continuous, the convergence is uniform on $\overline{A}$, hence on $A$.

Comment: This is actually a lot shorter.
Unfortunately, I've never heard of 'Lipschitz continuous' and have seen almost no theorems involving completions.
I'm just an 'intro to analysis' *student*.
I will look it up though.